# How to resolve this orientation problem in Android?

Tags: android

In my project I am taking one textview and one button and when I am  clicking on button I am displaying some text in the textview which I am getting from an arraylist.

When I change the orientation to landscape I am using onSavedInstanceState(...) and onRestoreInstanceState(..) and getting the text displayed on textview and in landscape mode I am removing the text on textview and I am changing the orientation to portrait but I am getting the text on textview.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

`TextView` saves its state by itself. If you don't want `TextView` to save its state, add `android:saveEnabled="false"` attribute or call `TextView.setSaveEnabled(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

On orientation changes, activity restarts. When an orientation change occurs Android calls a special method called onRetainNonConfigurationInstance. You can use this method to save an object, and afterwards you can get that object by using getLastNonConfigurationInstance method. You can see an example here

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: thanks for responding.. my problem is when i am making some changes i am able to reflect those changes when i change th orientation to landscape using onSavedInstanceState (...) and onRetainInstanceState(..) methods but when i make some changes in landscape mode i cant reflect in portrait mode..